# How to stop centering inside a table cell?

Tags: html, css

My question will become more clear with the linked JSFiddle below.

I would simply like each  to not be centered (height-wise) in the table cell it may be in.

Here the example showing my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qc1st2t9/

So, how can I use CSS to prevent a  from being centered inside of a table cell, when the table cell is much taller than the content inside of the unordered list?

Here is my code for those who may not want to visit jsfiddle:

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Events(1) | Covered Amount: 25/79 | Percent Covered: 32%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>first</td>
        <td>second</td>
        <td>third</td>
        <td>fourth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>test</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>test</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul></ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My attempts with CSS (I have removed rules that affected this in negative ways):

```
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align:left;
        width:100%;
        margin:auto;
    }
    th, td {
        border: 1px solid #cecfd5;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        height:25px;
        max-height:50px;
        text-align:left;
        width:25%;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    th > div {
        max-height:50px;
        overflow-y:scroll;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        text-align:left;
    }
```

Comment: Try vertical-align :middle;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use CSS: `vertical-align: top`.
See the [vertical align spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qc1st2t9/1/

Comment: Thank you Cristy, this was so hard to search for (for me, anyways). The words "centered" and "table cell" bring up many other results. Did you just happen to know this, or is there some better way of phrasing my question to bring up relevant results in google?

Comment: Also, I'll be marking this as the answer when the time limit is passed.

Comment: I already knew this, did not search for it, but searching for "align content top table" returns relevant results.